# Need help with epsilon delta proof that $\lim_{x\to 2}\sqrt{4x-x^2}=2$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, epsilon-delta

I need to prove the following statement using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\sqrt{4x-x^2}=2$$

I tried to calculate $|f(x)-2|$ and tried to simplify it to $|x-2|g(x)$ so I could limit delta (probably ≤ 1) and then calculate a bound for $g(x)$, and then let $\varepsilon=\min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{bound}\}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a good idea!

Comment: Did you encounter any problem?

Comment: Rewriting this as $\sqrt{4x-x^2} = \sqrt{4-(x^2-4x+4)} = \sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}$ might also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{4x-x^2}$.

We want to prove,using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method, that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=2$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and let $\delta=\min(2,\sqrt{2\epsilon})$.

Suppose $|x-2| < \delta$. Our goal is show $|f(x)-2| < \epsilon$.

Note that

$\qquad|x-2|<\delta  \implies |x-2| < 2 \implies 0 < x < 4 \implies f(x) >  0$.

Also note that

$\qquad|(f(x)-2)(f(x)+2)| = |f(x)^2-4| = |4x-x^2-4|=|-(x-2)^2|=(x-2)^2$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&|x-2| < \delta\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|x-2| < \sqrt{2\epsilon}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|x-2|^2 <  2\epsilon\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x-2)^2 <  2\epsilon\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|(f(x)-2)(f(x)+2)| <  2\epsilon\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|f(x)-2||f(x)+2| < 2\epsilon\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|f(x)-2|2 < 2\epsilon\\[0pt]
&\qquad\text{[since $f(x) > 0 \implies |f(x) + 2| = f(x) + 2 >2$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|f(x)-2| < \epsilon\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** 
$$\sqrt{4x-x^2}-2=(\sqrt{4x-x^2}-2)\times\dfrac{\sqrt{4x-x^2}+2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}+2}=\dfrac{-(x-2)^2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}+2}$$

Answer (score 2):

another point of wiew$$\forall \epsilon>0 , \delta >0 :|x-2|<\delta \implies |\sqrt{4x-x^2}-2|<\epsilon\\
|\frac{4x-x^2-4}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}+2}|<\epsilon\\
|\frac{-(x-2)^2}{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}+2}|\leq |\frac{-(x-2)^2}{0+2}|<\epsilon\\\to
|\frac{(x-2)^2}{2}|<\epsilon\\|(x-2)^2|<2\epsilon\\|\sqrt{4x-x^2}-2|\leq |x-2|<\sqrt{2\epsilon}
$$

Comment: It would have been better if you assumed $|x-2|<1$ and then get $\delta =\min(1,2\epsilon) $. One should avoid complicated expressions for $\delta$ which smack of algebraic manipulation of inequalities.

Comment: is this comlicated?

Comment: Well I would say it is not complicated. I just added you could have made it simpler (and OP was also expecting something like $\delta=\min(.,.) $).

Comment: You are right . I am thankful for your comment .

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rlcccl}
& -\varepsilon &<& \sqrt{4x-x^2}-2 &<& \varepsilon \\
\iff& 2-\varepsilon &<& \sqrt{4x-x^2} &<& 2+\varepsilon \\
\iff& 2-\varepsilon &<& \sqrt{4x-x^2} &\le& 2 \\
\iff& (2-\varepsilon)^2 &<& 4x-x^2 &\le& 4 \\
\iff& \varepsilon^2-4\varepsilon &<& -4+4x-x^2 &\le& 0 \\
\iff& \varepsilon^2-4\varepsilon &<& -(x-2)^2 &\le& 0 \\
\iff& 0 &\le& (x-2)^2 &<& 4\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2 \\
\iff& 0 &\le& |x-2| &<& \sqrt{4\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2} \\
\end{array}$$

It is assumed that $4\varepsilon-\varepsilon^2 \ge 0$, i.e. $\varepsilon \le 2$.

If $\varepsilon > 2$, then one only need to set $\delta=2$, for the domain of definition of $f$ is just $[0,4]$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last step?

Comment: @Orangalo sorry, fixed.

Comment: This is not the way things work. Definition of limit is not an exercise in the algebraic manipulation of inequalities. For example your answer does not make sense if $\varepsilon=5$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Indeed I assumed that $\varepsilon < 2$, because otherwise $\delta=2$ would suffice. You might want to point out why my approach is wrong apart from the unsubstantiated claim "definition of limit is not an exercise in the algebraic manipulation of inequalities"

Comment: The definition does not require one to solve the inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ to find all values of $x$ for which the inequality holds. Unfortunately most cheap textbooks also follow this algebraic manipulation of inequalities. The method fails miserably for simple examples like $\lim_{x\to a} x^{2}=a^{2}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don't see your objection if it works for this case. Note that each step is $\iff$, not $\implies$.

Comment: Also your third line does not follow automatically from second line. If $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ it is possible that $f(x) >L$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh my third line is because the maximum of $\sqrt{4x-x^2}$ is $2$...

Comment: I am aware of that. I wanted to say that such procedure can not be used in general. The method does work in this case.  If you edit the answer to add assumption of $\epsilon<2$ and also indicate how to deal with $\epsilon\geq 2$ then this can be treated as a correct answer. You can see that the assumption $\epsilon<2$ is used implicitly when you square line 3 to get to line 4.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh satisfied?